# Creat urls without extensions like wordpress

Tags: url

Hi I was wondering how to make the url on a website look like wordpress pretty permalinks or without extensions to be exact, but without having to make directories on the server.

I was thinking of putting a table in mysql of say 'url', 'meta' and 'id' and than always calling the index.php with htaccess and grab the uri of the url and redirect accordingly.

Would this be the best way or is it a horrible idea =). Can this be done in a way that google would still be able to crawl pages or should directories be made with index.php in them.

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: Your question is lacking important information. What software is your server running? Do you want to remove the extensions from simple html-files or are you running scripts?

Comment: server is linux and yes I would want to remove all extensions - query strings dont matter.

Comment: Again: what software is your server running? Is it an apache?

Comment: sorry about not replying I didn't know someone had replied, but it is apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you do something similar to the URL's overflow in Kohana ( http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/routing )? Basically, you let the user type any URL they want, then you parse this URL manually in your PHP code and redirect to the right controller / PHP file / class, whatever system you choose.

If the input URL is invalid, just throw a 404 error or redirect to your error page.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. So basically do it the way I am doing it using mysql to store urls and send to the page accordingly and if not send to error page. It looks as though they use htaccess and php instead of a database. - I will just give it a go and see what happens - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Good answer from this.lau_   For anyone else still reading this in 2015...
Generally there are a number of approaches to translating or going without extensions. Most of the posts are from people favouring (obsessed with ?) mod_rewrite, and it is true you could rewrite targets in a "case statement" way.  There is also mod_negotiate, which does not care for extensions, but globs the directory for filename.* and takes the first matching extension it can handle in a order of precedence.
Your SQLServer table is not such a bad idea either, with query_cache residence. The average blog browser will not be bothered.