# Understanding different website URLs

Tags: php, url

I am confused as to how, for example, this page is loaded. I am looking at the navigation bar in my browser and it says:

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

I am used to seeing this for the pages I develop:

```
Example.com/ask.php
```

Why does their URL not contain page names or values? Or does it? If so, how.

Thanks.

Comment: That's because SO has a framework in the background to tear apart that URL and use its components AS the values and passes them to a single controlling script. It's an example of the [MVC design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creat urls without extensions like wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029138/creat-urls-without-extensions-like-wordpress) and [many, many, many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=urls+without+file+extensions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL does not have to correspond to an actual pathname in the local filesystem on the server, that's just convention.

Often, the URL will be [rewritten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_rewriting).

Answer (score 1):

This kinds of jobs are usually done with URL rewriting. Depending on your server, there are several ways of achieving it.

The most famous one is the **[`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)** utilized in the **[`.htaccess`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess)** file **[Apache servers](http://www.apache.org/)** have.

Comment: .htaccess has nothing to do with rewriting. That's like saying parchment is the Magna Carta because the words were written on the parchment. URL rewriting in Apache is done using mod_rewrite, whose directives can be entered into a .htaccess file.